# How to visualize and export the output of ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.Ccdc?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am trying to visualize and export the output of `ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.Ccdc`, but all my attempts have failed. see my code for a working example. My goal is to get (export and visualize) all the outputs as multi bands image(s), so that I can check the correctness of the results and present them in other software (e.g. R).

[Link to code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/82ac089feaba69b7ade293a54fa75bde)